# How can I assign an int to a String variable?

Tags: java, string, variables, int

I am currently making an assignment for Java but I am stuck. I have to make a birthdate from the three parameters: day, month and year, which are numbers = int. With this I have to put in some checks for valid dates. That part I think is done, but I get stuck at the following:

I want an if statement to check the day, and if the day is correct, this block of code should be run trough

```
if (dag >=1 && dag <=31) 
{
    datum = dag; 
}
```

`datum` Is a String, because I want to get the date like this: DD-MM-YYY
And `dag` is an Int. So whenever I try to compile this, BlueJ gives an error at this part saying "incompatible types". I assume this is because I try to place a Int in a String. Is this possible in any way, because I can't find out how.

Answer (score 3):

Use `String.valueOf` method to convert `int` to `string`: -

```
int i = 32;
String str = String.valueOf(i);
```

And of course follow the advice in [@Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13572002/1679863) as to what you should rather do in your case.

Comment: Another option is `Integer.toString(i)`

Answer (score 3):

Don't make it a string. it's not. I think you should

1. create a [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) object to represent your date (day/month/year combined)
2. use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to print that date out in the appropriate format

That's the proper OO way to do it. Otherwise you end up with a bunch of disparate disconnected variables representing in their combination some object type, but you can't manipulate them atomically, invoke methods on them etc. Holding everything as strings is known as *stringly-typing* (as opposed to *strongly-typing*) and is a particularly bad code smell!

At some stage check out [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) for a better date/time API than those suggested above. However for the moment I suspect you've got enough on your plate without downloading extra jars.